# What features of router should I consider for Video Conference?

Tags: untagged

I am a beginner here. We have a small SOHO UTM router with a firewall speed 100 Mbps. We are going to install a video conferencing equipment which has 1080p video capabilities. What features set should I consider for the new router (like QoS etc)?

Comment: Shopping and/or product recommendation questions are off-topic here. Please see the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) and [QA is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more information.

Comment: Hi, EEAA, I am sorry, I didn't read those FAQs. So now I have changed my questions. I am new to networking and router features, so I like to know what features set are the most important to consider in streaming videos. Thanks.

Comment: The edited question was certainly within topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get away with the bottom end devices in the business grade class of equipment. Features you may need:

1) ALGs (Application Layer Gateways) - these make voice and video devices (and other protocols) play nice with NAT (network address translation). The ability to turn these OFF may also be critical depending on your videoconferencing gear.

2) QoS - you need a full blown QoS implementation that can give a small amount of buffers and high priority to the voice stream, and then give the rest of the priority to the video traffic and after that the rest of your traffic. QoS will not increase your bandwidth, it will reduce packetloss for one type of traffic at the expense of another.

3) NAT - You will probably need a device that can handle NAT in both directions, flexibly. Most SOHO devices just allow port forwarding, and typically don't ACTUALLY firewall.

Finally:

Not a feature of the firewall, but a feature of your ISP and the person you are calling:

BANDWIDTH... you will need 5Mbps of bandwidth or so to handle a 1080p stream while making a call. I'd say leave no less than 20% in reserve for your other traffic in case QoS cannot compensate. So let's say a solid 7-8Mb, if not 10Mb.

As for devices in this category? Here's a few:

1) Cisco ASA5505 (hard to configure NAT, ugly green color, I hate these things, but they ARE an industry standard).

2) Juniper SRX100 (harder to configure QoS, but an awesomely powerful OS, pretty box)

3) Sonicwall TZ120 (probably right up your alley, price and skillwise, tons of features).

Comment: Also, I did some rounding up on bandwidth numbers there to insulate you.